# Super Bowl commercial

Tags: idioms

Help please!

What does the boy on the bus say? Is that an idiom?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?x-yt-cl=85114404&v=dKUy-tfrIHY

Comment: He appears to be saying "or get cooties" which when added to his previous statement "I'll never get to ride a bike" makes up the sentence "I'll never get to ride a bike or get cooties" - I don't think "get cooties" counts as an idiom.

Comment: Thanks. Interestingly enough, I did not find any references to "cooties" in my Longman dictionary but there is an entry on the Wikipedia. So how am I supposed to know that? Only by having kids? :-)

Comment: Interesting that http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Cooties the Free Dictionary has a number of entries stating that it's _headlice - Pediculidae_. I always thought it was an imaginary germ.

Comment: From this wiki page:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooties#Cooties_game

"A child is said to "catch" cooties through any form of bodily contact, proximity, or touching of an "infected" person or from a person of the opposite sex of the same age. Often the "infected" person is someone who is perceived as "different", such as being of the opposite sex, disabled, shy..."

I think it fits the context of this commercial :-)

Comment: I never thought to check but OED has _cootie_ as slang (presumably UK) for _A body louse_ back in WW1 times but from the late 1960's as _orig. U.S. A contagious germ; esp. (chiefly Children's slang) an imaginary germ with which a socially undesirable person, or one of the opposite sex, is said to be infected. Usu. in pl._ I always thought it was American - learned something new today.

Comment: "learned something new today" 

Ditto!

Comment: Yep, "cooties" have been the scourge of the playground since I was a kid (a LONG time).  You can "get" cooties by contact (fully clothed!) with a member of the opposite sex, or by simply being "different".  If you "have cooties", others in your group will avoid your touch and will shun you.  Usually a playful concept, but occasionally used as a part of group bullying.

Comment: It wasn't until I was well into adulthood that I learned that cooties originally meant lice. As a child, I just knew the imaginary meaning. This meaning obviously emerged as a metaphor; when you suffer from this malady, you're shunned as if you had lice.

Comment: At least at my primary school cooties was more a metaphoric disease than an actual one.

Answer (score 3):

In the commercial a young boy says that he "will never get cooties", this is illustrated with a scene where a young boy is kissed on the cheek by a girl.

The literal meaning of [*cooties*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/cooties) is *lice* but the scene in the commercial is decidedly not about lice.

Instead, the expression "getting cooties" as used here derives from a childish expression of fear of the opposite sex.

[From OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/41083?rskey=4Zgdqd&result=2#eid):

> 2. orig. and chiefly U.S. A contagious germ; esp. (chiefly Children's slang) an imaginary germ said to have infected a person of the opposite sex or someone considered socially undesirable. Usually in pl.

There is a fairly widespread notion among young children that the opposite sex have these (purely imaginary) "cooties" and that you too will get cooties if you were to interact. Often this is seen in the context of young boys who think that romance and girls are gross and thus fear "girl cooties".

I think it's safe to say that the actual message of the scene is that this kid will never experience romance/falling in love.